# What is the Google Chrome address bar font?

Tags: google-chrome

I think I'm using the last Google Chrome version, which is 8.1. What is the font of the address bar? I'm on Windows 10.

Answer (score -1):

You can find it in Settings. Go to Advanced Settings and there is a place you can set the fonts and see what are the fonts that are being used. (On mac it's Preferences > Settings > Advanced Settings). See https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/uBAYr4WmZXU to confirm you can check font that way. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

According to me, the easy way to find a font is to do a printscreen of it, and then use a font finder like https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

It will analyse the text and gives you all matching fonts.